# GTK+, использование GError

Tags: c, gtk+

Помогите понять, как правильно работать с **GError**.

Изначально все казалось просто - если какая-то функция имеет вид:

```
... some_func(..., GError **_e);
```

То при **_e != NULL** в случае возникновения ошибки в **_e** записывается адрес на структуру **GError**, в которой хранится описание ошибки: домен, код и текст. При каждом возникновении ошибки выделяется память под новую структуру в динамической памяти.

Решил почитать документацию, чтобы убедиться в верности моего представления. В документации **GError** описан так, что я совсем запутался. Слишком много всяких уточнений. Очень плохая документация...

Скажите, могу ли я *накапливать* информацию об ошибках, то есть, действительно ли все генерируемые **GError** независимы друг от друга?

Вот что я подразумеваю под накапливанием ошибок:

```
void big_func(void)
{
    GError *error;
    list *errors = list_new();

    error = NULL;
    some_func_1(&error);
    if (error != NULL)
        list_push(errors, error);

    error = NULL;
    some_func_2(&error);
    if (error != NULL)
        list_push(errors, error)

    error = NULL;
    some_func_3(&error);
    if (error != NULL)
        list_push(errors, error)

    // Анализ и обработка ошибок.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: что именно ты понимаешь под «накапливанием ошибок»? кусок кода в качестве примера будет уместен...

Comment: Добавил пример, что я имел в виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Независимы ли инстансы GError друг от друга?

**Все верно, они независимы.**

В документации четко указаны способы их создания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И удаления:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что делаете вы - возможная реализация для "накопления ошибок". Но вы **обязательно должны почистить ваш список** не просто освобождая память под указатели, но и освобождая память, занятую теми самыми GError структурами:

```
// я синтаксис вашего листа не знаю, так что псевдокод
foreach error in errors:
    g_error_free(error)
delete errors
```

---

Правда не совсем понятно, почему вы в принципе хотите накапливать ошибки. В документации (да и по логике) хотя бы одна ошибка означает провал при исполнении кода. Возьмем те же [правила использования GError](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#gerror-rules):

> "Piling up" errors is always a bug. That is, if you assign a new
>   GError to a GError* that is non-NULL, thus overwriting the previous
>   error, it indicates that you should have aborted the operation instead
>   of continuing. If you were able to continue, you should have cleared
>   the previous error with g_clear_error(). g_set_error() will complain
>   if you pile up errors.

Да, тут говорится про то, что лучше не стоит перезаписывать одну и ту же ошибку, у вас другой случай. Проблема в другом, если у вас каждая следующая функция зависит от предыдущей, то провал первой функции автоматически означает провал всех последующих - вам банально не за чем проверять, что там сломалось в самом конце, если проблема изначально возникла в самом начале.

Дело ваше, но я лично я бы не советовал "накапливать" ошибки и потом всем скопом их проверять, если на это нет какой-то серьезной причины, например, вы обрабатываете большой объем данных, и провал на очередной порции данных никак не влияет на следующий.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что список нужно будет правильно чистить. Накапливать ошибки мне необходимо потому, что в некоторых ситуациях дальнейшая логика не зависит от успешности предыдущих действий, поэтому делать миллион **if-else** - решение так себе.

Comment: @Максим, тогда да, такой вариант имеет право на существование